# BigQuery position function for element within a nested element

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I get the position for a field nested in multiple level of records:

```
select position(repeatedRec.rec1.field)
```

where repeatedRec is a repeated record, and rec1 is a non-repeated record? Assume that repeatedRec doesn't have any other leaves. I need to know what is repeatedRec position for the element in which rec1.field resides.

This doesn't seem to work, and all I get is 1 (as if the system is treating the field as a non repeated field).

Comment: does `position(repeatedRec.rec1)` not work?

Comment: no, because repeatedRec.rec1 isn't a leaf field

Comment: `position` returns the position inside that repeated field. So you should be using something like `position(repeatedRec)` only, not so?

Comment: position will only work on leaf fields. Both repeatedRec and repeatedRec.rec1 are not leaves

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
select position(repeatedRec.rec1.field) WHITHIN repeatedRec.rec1 as f1
```

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#within
see this link for a small documentation on within

Comment: I tried this, and there is an error: Scope applied without an aggregation function